# User Trigger to Assign Lead Lookup not firing

Tags: class, before-trigger

I'm a bit stumped as to why this isn't firing. It's supposed to work when a User Lookup field called ISR_Owner__c on a User record is updated it will try to find all Leads owner by that User. It will then assign the Leads ISR_Owner__c field to the User's ISR_Owner__c. It's currently just doing nothing, no errors just not working. Any insight into what could be going wrong here?

**Trigger:**

```
    trigger MasterUserTrigger on User (
  before insert, after insert, 
  before update, after update, 
  before delete, after delete,
  after undelete) {

  if (Trigger.isBefore) {
    if (Trigger.isInsert) {


    } 
    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
    isrLeadSync ISRToSync = new isrLeadSync(Trigger.new);
        ISRToSync.syncISRs();
            }
    if (Trigger.isDelete) {

    }
  }

  if (Trigger.IsAfter) {
    if (Trigger.isInsert) {

    } 
    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {

    }
    if (Trigger.isDelete) {

    }
    if (Trigger.isUndelete){

      }
  }
}
```

**Class:**

```
public class isrLeadSync {

    List<User> users;

    public isrLeadSync(List<User> triggerUser){
        users = triggerUser;
    }

    public void syncISRs(){
        for (User u : users){
        if(u.ISR_Owner__c != null && u.ISR_Owner__r.IsActive){
            List<Lead> leadList = [SELECT Id, ISR_Owner__c 
                                     FROM Lead 
                                     WHERE OwnerId = : u.Id 
                                     AND ISR_Owner__c != : u.ISR_Owner__c];   

        for(Lead l : leadList){
            l.ISR_Owner__c = u.ISR_Owner__c;
        }

        update leadList;
        } 
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Two questions. 1. Is trigger active? 2. How you are checking that it is not working?

Comment: I've linked a question that is relevant to your trigger. Relationship fields **are not provided** by default, so you can't figure out if the ISR_Owner__c record is active or not without performing a query.

Comment: Also, as a side note, your code should be bulkified in order to avoid errors when mass updating records.